# Strange behaviour of JPA native query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use JPA native query but I am not getting the expected result.

I tried both lazy and eager fetching strategy but the issue is same.

```
public class OfferDetailEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "prod_spec_code")
  private String productSpecificationCode;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "offer_detail_id")
  private Collection<ServiceEntity> services;
}


public class ServiceEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "service_name")
  private String serviceName;

  @Column(name = "service_id")
  private Long serviceId;

}
```

And native query which is generated dynamically is

```
select * from offer_detail_entity detail inner join service_entity service 
       on service.offer_detail_id=detail.id  where prod_spec_code = 'AT52476'
         and service_name = 'Airtel'
```

It gives all the services associated with `OfferDetailEntity`. 
But the expected service is only one having `service_name = 'Airtel'`.
I tried to debug and found that hibernate is executing one more query. 
I am not sure why hibernate needs services again when I already joined in native query.
Extra query generated by hibernate

```
select
        services0_.offer_detail_id as offe4_11_0_,
        services0_.id as id1_11_0_,
        services0_.id as id1_11_1_,
        services0_.service_id as service_2_11_1_,
        services0_.service_name as service_3_11_1_ 
    from
        offer_service services0_ 
    where`enter code here`
        services0_.offer_detail_id=?
```

Kindly provide me a solution.

Comment: 1) When you use native queries (```EntityManager#createNativeQuery```), you specify all the joins manually. In htis case FetchType (EAGER/LAZY) doesn't affect anything.  2) In the example you show ```ServiceEntity``` but in ```OfferDetailEntity``` I can see the list of **Vms**ServiceEntity. It's confusing. Did you post wrong entity?

Comment: It was a type mistake, I edited it.

Comment: use 1 )  @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager; 2 ) Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(yournative Query);

Comment: List<OfferDetailEntity> offers = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query,OfferDetailEntity.class)
                .getResultList(); Is there any issue in this.

Comment: Because you are eagerly loading the collection. The first query is to select the `OfferDetailEntity` which contains a sevice with the given name. The second one is to properly initialize the `offer_detail_entity` with all the referenced services. Those cannot be part of the initial query with the join due to the `where` clause. It would be an incorrect representation of the actual state of the `OfferDetailEntity` according to your mappings. When using lazy the same query will eventually be issued but later as soon as you access the collection.

Comment: Actually I just need the exact data whatever I want, I don't need maintain the state. Could you please provide me the solution. I tried your suggestion to use @PersistenceContext but still the result is same.

Comment: I am able to do the same thing via @Query of JPA. But in this scenario my where clause is fully dynamic that's y I am trying to do it via native query. If not possible please let me know the good approach to put where clause dynamically considering that I have lots of column in a table and lots of join.